# Finding Max of Array of Objects/Writing To File

Tags: java, class

I am trying to find the max score from the array of objects. The code for that is everything below the int maxValue = -1; line of code. I am also trying to write that bands information to an external file:

```
import java.io.FileWriter;


public class App {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    Bands[] bands = new Bands[5];

    bands[0] = new Bands("Joe", "Rick", "Nick", "Dalton", "Doylestown, PA", "RockOn", 4000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[1] = new Bands("Luke", "Bill", "Ian", "Matt", "State College, PA", "Blink182", 3500.50 , "Alternative");
    bands[2] = new Bands("Corey", "Noah", "Jon", "Kaleb", "Philadelphia, PA", "Rise Against", 10000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[3] = new Bands("Jake", "Joey", "Mike", "Mac", "New York, NY", "Thousand Foot Krutch", 2000.50 , "Rock");
    bands[4] = new Bands("Bob", "Jeff", "Dom", "Mark", "King of Prussia, PA", "Skillet", 5500.50 , "Rock");

    bands[0].compete();
    bands[1].compete();
    bands[2].compete();
    bands[3].compete();
    bands[4].compete();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        String bandInfo = bands[i].getInfo();
        System.out.println(bandInfo);
    }

    System.out.println("");


    //DOESNT WORK BEYOND THIS POINT



    int maxValue = -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
        if (bands[i].compete() > maxValue) {
            maxValue = bands[i].compete();
        }
    }

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/winners.txt", true);
        fw.write(bandInfo + "\n");
        fw.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And then here is my Bands class code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Bands {

private String singerName;
private String guitarName;
private String bassistName;
private String drummerName;
private String Hometown;
private String bandName;
private double income;
private String genre;
private int score;
private int winningBand;

public Bands(String singerName, String guitarName, String bassistName, String drummerName, String Hometown, String bandName, double income, String genre)
{
    this.singerName = singerName;
    this.guitarName = guitarName;
    this.bassistName = bassistName;
    this.drummerName = drummerName;
    this.bandName = bandName;
    this.Hometown = Hometown;
    this.income = income;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.score = -1;
    this.winningBand = -1;
}

public void compete()
{     
    Random rand = new Random();
    this.score = rand.nextInt(20);
}

public int getScore() 
{
    return this.score;
}

public String getInfo()
{
    String bandInfo = "Band: " + this.bandName + ", Singer: " + this.singerName + ", Guitarist: " + this.guitarName + ", Bassist: " + this.bassistName + 
                      ", Drummer: " + this.drummerName + ", Hometown: " + this.Hometown + ", Income: " + this.income + ", Genre: " + 
                      this.genre + ", Final Score: " + this.score;

    return bandInfo;
}
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for your question about only printing band with highest score info:

Create a global variable (In this case I called it winningBand as an Integer)
Then edit your loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
   if (bands[i].getScore() > maxValue) {
      maxValue = bands[i].getScore();
      winningBand = i;
   }
}
```

Then when you write to the file, only write the winningBand:

```
try {
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/winners.txt", true);
   fw.write(band[winningBand].getInfo);
   fw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Now I understand what you were talking about. I must be doing something wrong because it says that it cannot find the variable winningBand in the file write statement

Comment: You need to make it a global variable. Don't declare it inside a method. Declare it where you declare your singer name etc.

Comment: I declared it in my Bands class which is where i declared my other variables, it still says it cannot find it. I know that Im doing something very wrong, but I cannot figure it out. I changed my code in the original question at the top, it still doesn't seem correct though?

Comment: My bad. The variable needs to be global in the other class, not band class.

Comment: No worries! It works now, thank you so much for all of your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the highest score? Well in your code below

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
    if (bands[i].compete() > maxValue) {
        maxValue = bands[i].compete();
    }
}
```

When you say .compete(), this does nothing. It assigns a random score in the Bands class. Instead it should look like this if you want to compare scores.

```
 for (int i = 0; i < bands.length; i++) {
    if (bands[i].getScore() > maxValue) {
        maxValue = bands[i].getScore();
    }
}
```

NOTE: You need to write a getScore() method in the band class that returns the score like the one below:

```
public Integer getScore(){
    return score;
}
```

Comment: it seems to be working now. do you know how i would write the information pertaining to the band to the file. For example, the highest score is related to a band and I would like to write that bands info to an external file. i seem to be able to write the score, but i am unsure about the information.

Comment: Check my other post.

Answer (score 0):

As for your question about writing to the file, this should work:

```
try {
    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("src/winners.txt", true);
       for(int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
          fw.write(band[i].getInfo + "\n");
       }
    fw.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: That does work in terms of writing all of the bands to the file, so thank you for that! Do you have any idea of how I can write only the band with the highest score to the file each time?

Comment: Simply create an new variable of type Integer. In the loop where you find the highest value, set this new variable to i (the current band with the highest score). Then edit the code above, remove the for loop, and only write band[variable you created].getInfo

Comment: Is there any way you could possibly show me, because I am having trouble visualizing it?

Comment: Yes look below.